# скачать звук на c#

Tags: c#, аудио, youtube

возникла необходимость скачать аудио дорожку с youtube и музыку с вк и яндек все это на c#.
пробовал через официальное api не нашёл. не официальное api для этих дел на c# тоже не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ на англоязычном SO. Это поможет скачать только аудиодорожку с видео на YouTube. Оригинал ответа: [клик](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877884/c-sharp-download-the-sound-of-a-youtube-video)

> Установите пакеты **NuGet**: `MediaToolkit` и `VideoLibrary`, это позволит вам выполнить преобразование по расширению файла.

```
var source = @"<your destination folder>";
var youtube = YouTube.Default;
var vid = youtube.GetVideo("<video url>");
File.WriteAllBytes(source + vid.FullName, vid.GetBytes());

var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = source + vid.FullName };
var outputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = $"{source + vid.FullName}.mp3" };

using (var engine = new Engine())
{
    engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);

    engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Советую посмотреть в сторону Selenium. Но сразу же спойлеры (скачать будет не так изи и на долгосрочную перспективу прогу не напишешь, потому что сервисфы постоянно меняют свое устройство и поэтому прогу надо будет сопровождать соответственно). Так же будет проблема, если музыка авторская, на ютюбчике она вообще защищена шифрованием и качнуть ее просто так не выйдет.Сервисы коммерческие и от таких энтузиастов как мы уже защитились...